# Nougat Music audio volume gets dropped suddenly with "Google quick search bar APP"

Tags: android, media-player

In my device which is on Android N (7.1.2),Music Player (Play Music application) Volume suddenly goes down if "Google quick search bar APP" is Launched and Volume comes back to normal as soon as we minimizes the Google quick search bar application

tried to put and debug with logs in below files but didnt get the root cause
frameworks/base/media/java/android/media/AudioManager.java
frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/audio/AudioService.java

Any advise how the Music Volume Fades in and Fades out ?

Logs for Reference:

```
01-01 07:52:51.668 437-7351/? D/audio_hw_primary: copl(0xac8c46c0):out of compress_wait
01-01 07:52:51.668 437-7353/? D/audio_hw_primary: copl(0xac8c46c0): writing buffer (65536 bytes) to compress device
01-01 07:52:51.669 437-7353/? D/audio_hw_primary: copl(0xac8c46c0): writing buffer (65536 bytes) to compress device
01-01 07:52:51.672 437-7353/? D/audio_hw_primary: No space available in compress driver, post msg to cb thread
01-01 07:52:51.672 437-7351/? D/audio_hw_primary: copl(0xac8c46c0):calling compress_wait
01-01 07:52:53.839 971-1186/system_process I/Test_log: AudioService.java :handleMessage::msg:{ when=-1ms what=5 arg2=-1000 target=com.android.server.audio.AudioService$AudioHandler }
01-01 07:52:53.839 971-1186/system_process I/Test_log: AudioService.java :handleMessage::msg.what:5
01-01 07:52:53.839 971-1186/system_process I/Test_log: AudioService.java :handleMessage: onPlaySoundEffect:msg.arg1:0
01-01 07:52:53.839 971-1186/system_process I/Test_log: AudioService.java :handleMessage: onPlaySoundEffect:msg.arg2:-1000
01-01 07:52:53.839 971-1186/system_process I/Test_log: onPlaySoundEffect_11111
01-01 07:52:53.840 971-1186/system_process I/Test_log: AudioService.java : onPlaySoundEffect: stackdump
                                                      java.lang.Throwable: stack dump
                                                          at com.android.server.audio.AudioService$AudioHandler.onPlaySoundEffect(AudioService.java:4689)
                                                          at com.android.server.audio.AudioService$AudioHandler.handleMessage(AudioService.java:4811)
                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                          at com.android.server.audio.AudioService$AudioSystemThread.run(AudioService.java:4455)


                                                      --------- beginning of system
01-01 07:52:53.840 971-1409/system_process I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.search.action.GLOBAL_SEARCH cat=[com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox.category.SEARCH_WIDGET] flg=0x10008000 cmp=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.apps.gsa.searchnow.SearchNowActivity bnds=[191,145][593,243] (has extras)} from uid 10035 on display 0
01-01 07:52:53.862 437-655/? D/audio_hw_primary: start_output_stream: enter: stream(0xac8c41c0)usecase(1: low-latency-playback) devices(0x2)
01-01 07:52:53.862 437-655/? D/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: out_snd_device(2: speaker) in_snd_device(0: )
01-01 07:52:53.862 437-655/? D/hardware_info: hw_info_append_hw_type : device_name = speaker
01-01 07:52:53.862 437-655/? W/audio_hw_utils: audio_extn_utils_update_stream_app_type_cfg: App type could not be selected. Falling back to default
01-01 07:52:53.862 437-655/? I/audio_hw_primary: select_devices Selected apptype: 69936
01-01 07:52:53.863 437-655/? V/audio_hw_dolby: audio_extn_dolby_set_dmid Dolby device manufacturer id is:0
01-01 07:52:53.864 437-655/? V/audio_hw_dolby: audio_extn_dolby_set_license Setting DS1 License, key:0x0 dmid 0
01-01 07:52:53.864 437-655/? E/DAP_HAL: dap_hal_set_hw_info: dmid=0
                                         key 00x
01-01 07:52:53.883 437-655/? E/audio_hw_dolby: audio_extn_dolby_set_license Could not set DS1 License. Status: -1
01-01 07:52:53.883 437-655/? E/audio_hw_dolby: audio_extn_dolby_ds2_set_endpoint: Dolby set endpint :0x2
01-01 07:52:53.883 437-655/? D/soundtrigger: audio_extn_sound_trigger_update_stream_status: uc_id 1 of type 0 for Event 3, with Raise=0
01-01 07:52:53.883 437-655/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_audio_cal, acdb_id = 14, path =  0
01-01 07:52:53.883 437-655/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_asm_topology
01-01 07:52:53.883 437-655/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AUDPROC_STREAM_TOPOLOGY_ID
01-01 07:52:53.883 437-655/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_adm_topology
01-01 07:52:53.883 437-655/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AUDPROC_COMMON_TOPOLOGY_ID
01-01 07:52:53.884 437-655/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_audtable
01-01 07:52:53.884 437-655/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AUDPROC_COMMON_TABLE_SIZE
01-01 07:52:53.884 437-655/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AUDPROC_COMMON_TABLE
01-01 07:52:53.884 437-655/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> AUDIO_SET_AUDPROC_CAL
01-01 07:52:53.884 437-655/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_audvoltable
01-01 07:52:53.884 437-655/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AUDPROC_GAIN_DEP_STEP_TABLE
01-01 07:52:53.884 437-655/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> AUDIO_SET_AUDPROC_VOL_CAL
01-01 07:52:53.884 437-655/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_afe_cal
01-01 07:52:53.884 437-655/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AFE_COMMON_TABLE
01-01 07:52:53.885 437-655/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> AUDIO_SET_AFE_CAL
01-01 07:52:53.885 437-655/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_hw_delay : acdb_id = 14 path = 0
01-01 07:52:53.885 437-655/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_AVSYNC_INFO: ACDB_CMD_GET_DEVICE_PROPERTY
01-01 07:52:53.885 437-655/? I/audio_hw_utils: audio_extn_utils_send_app_type_cfg: PLAYBACK  app_type 69936, acdb_dev_id 14, sample_rate 48000
01-01 07:52:53.886 437-655/? D/audio_hw_primary: enable_audio_route: apply mixer and update path: low-latency-playback
01-01 07:52:53.887 437-655/? D/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: done
01-01 07:52:53.892 971-1409/system_process I/ActivityManager: Killing 6348:com.android.musicfx/u0a24 (adj 906): empty for 3043s
01-01 07:52:53.900 437-655/? D/msm8916_platform: platform_set_channel_map mixer_ctl_name:Playback Channel Map12
01-01 07:52:53.900 437-655/? D/msm8916_platform: platform_set_channel_map: set mapping(1 2 3 0 0 0 0 0) for channel:2
01-01 07:52:53.900 437-655/? D/audio_hw_primary: start_output_stream: exit
01-01 07:52:53.901 971-1409/system_process D/ActivityTrigger: ActivityTrigger activityPauseTrigger 
01-01 07:52:53.923 2096-2096/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/LegacyNowServiceClient: skipping logEndstates, service is null
01-01 07:52:53.964 371-371/? W/SurfaceFlinger: couldn't log to binary event log: overflow.
01-01 07:52:53.994 2096-2096/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@15c0524
01-01 07:52:53.995 2096-2096/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@b97588d
01-01 07:52:53.995 2096-2096/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@679da42
01-01 07:52:53.995 2096-2096/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@36e3a53
01-01 07:52:54.000 2096-2096/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@9adf089
01-01 07:52:54.000 2096-2096/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@14f588e
01-01 07:52:54.033 971-1576/system_process D/ActivityManager: cleanUpApplicationRecord -- 6348
01-01 07:52:54.039 2096-2096/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@84a5e43
01-01 07:52:54.039 2096-2096/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@b34bcc0
01-01 07:52:54.174 971-1029/system_process I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.apps.gsa.searchnow.SearchNowActivity: +247ms
01-01 07:52:54.183 5385-5466/com.android.launcher3 D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x898dc380 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x93e15e20
01-01 07:52:54.190 437-7353/? D/audio_hw_primary: out_set_parameters: enter: usecase(3: compress-offload-playback) kvpairs: routing=2
01-01 07:52:54.245 1217-1217/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin W/InputMethodService: Window size has been changed. This may cause jankiness of resizing window: -1 -> -2
```

Answer (score 0):

When you play audio on an Android device the application has to request audio focus. The operating system has different ways of dealing with a conflict in audio focus, it either performs audio ducking, stops the audio briefly, or completely hands over control to another application that requests focus:

From [Managing audio focus](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-focus) Android documentation:

> Two or more Android apps can play audio to the same output stream
>   simultaneously. The system mixes everything together. While this is
>   technically impressive, it can be very aggravating to a user. To avoid
>   every music app playing at the same time, Android introduces the idea
>   of audio focus. Only one app can hold audio focus at a time.

**TL;DR:** It sounds to me like the Google Search bar is requesting audio focus, perhaps for voice control, and the OS is ducking your application audio briefly during this action - after which audio focus is handed back to your application.

See [Managing audio focus](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-focus) for more detail.

Comment: Thanks for the comments , I checked  in one of the other development product ( also on android N)and also Nexus 9 , Music plays smoothly without any ducking

Comment: What are the details of the device that is having the issues? Could it be an issue with the proprietary software of the particular brand? Not all Android OSs are created equal and are stock :)

Comment: I have two different devices both  are on same android version 7.1.2 and in other device Music plays smoothly even with Google quickserachbar  (there is no any proprietary software change)and this audiofocusand automatic ducking seems to be introduced from android 8.0

Comment: I hear you, but different brands introduce third party software that could affect audio playback. What exact models are they?